# How can I move inside the scene with a midle mouse without limits?

Tags: animation, scene, mouse

I need to record a camera movement by using the mouse (scrolling or ctrl + Middle Mouse) but the problem is it just stops very quickly and doesn`t let me passing through the whole scene, is there a way to expand it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for "continuous grab" it can be turned on/off under User pref->Interface. Alternatively you can "focus view" with alt+midclick while hovering over something. Or you could type "walk/fly navigation" after hitting space. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No worries :) good blending!